# How to convert Markdown-style links using regex?

Tags: ruby, regex, markdown

I'm trying to write a regular expression that replaces a markdown-style links but it doesn't seem to be working. This is what I have so far:

```
# ruby code:
text = "[link me up](http://www.example.com)"
text.gsub!(%r{\[(\+)\]\((\+)\)}x, %{<a target="_blank" href="\\1">\\2</a>})
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not use a full Ruby Markdown library, like the wonderful [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/)?

Comment: because I only need a limited subset of markdown features and haven't found a library that allows me to specify which features I want to support (so I'm having to write my own).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
irb(main):001:0> text = "[link me up](http://www.example.com)"
irb(main):002:0> text.gsub /\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/, '<a href="\2">\1</a>'
#=> "<a href=\"http://www.example.com\">link me up</a>"
```

We can use the e`x`tended option for Ruby's regex to make it not look like a cat jumped on the keyboard:

```
def linkup( str )
  str.gsub %r{
    \[         # Literal opening bracket
      (        # Capture what we find in here
        [^\]]+ # One or more characters other than close bracket
      )        # Stop capturing
    \]         # Literal closing bracket
    \(         # Literal opening parenthesis
      (        # Capture what we find in here
        [^)]+  # One or more characters other than close parenthesis
      )        # Stop capturing
    \)         # Literal closing parenthesis
  }x, '<a href="\2">\1</a>'
end

text = "[link me up](http://www.example.com)"
puts linkup(text)
#=> <a href="http://www.example.com">link me up</a>
```

Note that the above will fail for URLs that have a right parenthesis in them, e.g.

```
linkup "[O](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050(v=vs.85).aspx)"
# <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050(v=vs.85">O</a>.aspx)
```

If this is important to you, you replace the `[^)]+` with `\S+(?=\))` which means *"find as many non-whitespace-characters as you can, but ensure that there is a `)` afterwards"*.

---

To answer your question *"what am I doing wrong"*, here's what your regex said:

```
%r{
  \[      # Literal opening bracket   (good)
    (     # Start capturing           (good)
      \+  # A literal plus character  (OOPS)
    )     # Stop capturing            (good)
  \]      # Literal closing bracket   (good)
  \(      # Literal opening paren     (good)
    (     # Start capturing           (good)
      \+  # A literal plus character  (OOPS)
    )     # Stop capturing            (good)
  \)      # Literal closing paren     (good)
}x
```

Comment: also, I've never seen a URL with parenthesis. I didn't even think this was valid. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Awesome explanation. Would've given more than +1 if possible. I ended up doing a matcher for [[foobar]] kind of syntax using your advice. Here's my go at it (simplified from yours): /\\[\\[([^\\]]+)\\]\\]/ .

Comment: To support tooltips, like `[link](http://example.com "tooltip")`, use this regex: `/\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)"]+)(?: \"([^\"]+)\")?\)/`

Comment: Just wanted to note that based on the common mark spec, opening and closing brackets in a URL are allowed. So a url like `http://example.com?query[]=something` should be allowed, but the regex provided does not account for that.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Incorrect. The regex prevents a closed bracket within the link text, but not within the URL. See http://rubular.com/r/kG7s9bHlOl for example.

Comment: @Phrogz Hi, so sorry. I put the URL in the `[]` instead of the `()` because I'm an idiot. Sorry for wasting your time. I'm going to try and adapt your solution to work with bracket escaping. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I don't think this works for URLs that end with a `)`

Comment: @étale-cohomology Did you read the part of my answer that says, _"Note that the above will fail for URLs that have a right parenthesis in them"_? And did you then read the part of the answer that starts with, _"If this is important to you…"_?