# Iterate over links in markdown content in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am wondering is it possible in Jekyll to iterate over elements of the processed page content in Jekyll Liquid filters, in particular to iterate over all the `<a>` elements on the page and get their their content and `href` attributes.

I'd like to be able to have something in a page like

```
<ul>
{% for link in content.links %}
  <li>so something here with {{link.contents}} and {{link.href}}.</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Is there any native feature or plugin that would allow something like this? It does not have to be compatible with Github Pages.

---

### Edit:

I ended up making a modified version of the plugin Christian suggested in their answer that captures reference-style links as well and excludes images.

```rb
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :pre_render do |site|
    site.collections.each do |collection, files|

        if files.docs.any?
            files.docs.each do |file|

                links = []

                inline_regex = /[^!]\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/
                referenced_regex = /\[([^\]]+)\](?:\[([^\]]+)\])?[^:]/
                references_regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]: ?(.+)/
                
                file.content.scan(inline_regex).each do |match|
                    if match.length == 2
                        links << { 
                            "text" => match[1],
                            "ref" => match[1],
                            "link_url" => match[2]
                        } 
                    end
                end

                file.content.scan(referenced_regex).each do |d_match|
                    if d_match.length == 2
                        link = { "text" => d_match[0], "ref" => d_match[1] }
                    elsif d_match.label == 1
                        link = { "text" => d_match[0], "ref" => d_match[0] }
                    end
                    file.content.scan(references_regex).each do |s_match|
                        if s_match[0] == link["ref"] and s_match[1]
                            links << link.merge!({"url" => s_match[1]})
                        end
                    end
                end

                file.merge_data!({"links" => links})
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over a dynamically generated front matter attribute.

The page front matter will contain the link texts and URLs matched by a regular expression.

#### Jekyll include file

To avoid repetitions, I have created an include file for your code snippet in **_includes\link_info.html**.

```
<ul>
    {% for link in page.links %}
    <li>so something here with {{link.link_text}} and {{link.link_url}}.</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

You can insert the include file code in your layout(s) or each post individually. A sample post could be:

```
---
layout: default
title:  "Your page title"
---

{% include link_info.html %}

[google](https://www.google.com)
```

#### Plugin to generate the links front matter attribute on each page

I have created a plugin using the [pre-render hook](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/hooks/) in **_plugins\links_in_documents.rb**:

```
# This plugin dynamically adds the frontmatter attribute. This covers documents in all collections including posts.
# It does not cover non-collection pages like index, search or 404 pages, on which attributes have to be set manually.
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :pre_render do |site|
    site.collections.each do |collection, files|

      if files.docs.any?
        files.docs.each do |file|

          # empty page.links array for the particular file
          links = []

          # Regex from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268407/how-to-convert-markdown-style-links-using-regex
          # Any other link types would require adjusting the regex to match the different types.
          regex = /\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)/
          match = file.content.match(regex)

          # insert any link into the array
          if match 
            ## debug output on jekyll serve
            # puts "link #{match} found in #{file.relative_path}" 
            links << { "link_text" => match[1], "link_url" => match[2] } 
          end

          # merges data in the page front matter
          file.merge_data!({"links" => links})
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought manually doing this in a plugin would end up being more complicated but this makes sense. I do like to use reference-style links in markdown which will require some adjustment, but that should hopefully still be doable with two regexes and matching the results together.

Comment: Cool that you like it.Maybe you can post your link style and regex as a reference for future readers.